# Accessing a C++ vector in a vector of vectors without copying it

Tags: c++, vector

If I create a vector of vectors like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVectorOfVectors;
```

Then populate it with a few things:

```
std::vector<int> myVector1;
myVector1.push_back(1);
myVector1.push_back(2);
myVector1.push_back(3);
myVector1.push_back(4);
myVectorOfVectors.push_back(myVector1);

std::vector<int> myVector2;
myVector2.push_back(1);
myVector2.push_back(2);
myVector2.push_back(3);
myVector2.push_back(4);
myVectorOfVectors.push_back(myVector2);

std::vector<int> myVector3;
myVector3.push_back(1);
myVector3.push_back(2);
myVector3.push_back(3);
myVector3.push_back(4);
myVectorOfVectors.push_back(myVector3);
```

How can I assign any given element of myVectorOfVectors to a variable without copying it? For example, I'm pretty sure the following will copy the vector located at index N:

```
std::vector<int> myVector = myVectorOfVectors[N];
```

Is there some way to get a pointer to the object at index N rather then a copy of the object at index N? How would I do this?

Comment: `operator[]` gives you a reference.

Comment: "Is there some way to get a pointer to the object" – why not use the address-of operator for generating pointers? `&myVector[N]` is a pointer to the N-th element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a reference.

```
std::vector<int>& myVector = myVectorOfVectors[N];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto&` and you won't have to repeat the type:

```cpp
auto& myVector = myVectorOfVectors[N];
```

Note: c++11 required.